# How to combine multiple .cs files into one for xamarin.ios

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I need to combine multiple c# files into one big file for xamarin.ios in pre-build event. This is because xamarin.ios allow write code for binding only in few files, which is quite terrible. So I'd like to have normal structure, and then merge all those files into few files:

```
Extras.cs
Structs.cs
ApiDefinition.cs
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are two options. 1st one it to do the above. 2nd - write all code in 3 files which will become huge. If there is 3rd - please let me know.

Comment: Maybe Xamarin's iOS binding guide will be helpful: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/macios/binding/objective-c-libraries/

Comment: What about `partial` classes?

Comment: are you serious ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case somebody needs a solution. It's actually very simple. There are two special build actions in xamarin.ios binding project:

- ObjcBindingApiDefinition
- ObjcBindingCoreSource

[image: ObjcBindingApiDefinition]

All files which have those build actions will be used to generate bindings. The first one act like `ApeDefinition.cs`, second one - `Structs.cs`.

The `Extras.cs` is all files which have `Compile` build action. This is it.

Hope it helps and save some time to somebody.